# Generating all combinations from a table in Lua

Tags: lua, combinations

I'm trying to iterate through a table with a variable amount of elements and get all possible combinations, only using every element one time. I've landed on the solution below.

```
arr = {"a","b","c","d","e","f"}

function tablelen(table)
  local count = 0
  for _ in pairs(table) do 
    count = count + 1 
  end
  return count
end

function spellsub(table,start,offset)
  local str = table[start]
  for i = start+offset, (tablelen(table)+1)-(start+offset) do
    str = str..","..table[i+1]
  end
  return str
end

print(spellsub(arr,1,2))    -- Outputs: "a,d,e" correctly
print(spellsub(arr,2,2))    -- Outputs: "b"     supposed to be "b,e,f"
```

I'm still missing some further functions, but I'm getting stuck with my current code. What is it that I'm missing? It prints correctly the first time but not the second?

Comment: If you work it out with pencil and paper, when you hit that for loop on your second time through, i is supposed to loop from 2+2 through to (6+1) - (2+2), or 4 through 3.  So basically, that for loop ends before it starts.

Answer (score 2):

A solution with a coroutine iterator called recursively:

```lua
local wrap, yield = coroutine.wrap, coroutine.yield

-- This function clones the array t and appends the item new to it.
local function append (t, new)
    local clone = {}
    for _, item in ipairs (t) do
        clone [#clone + 1] = item
    end
    clone [#clone + 1] = new
    return clone
end

--[[
    Yields combinations of non-repeating items of tbl.
    tbl is the source of items,
    sub is a combination of items that all yielded combination ought to contain,
    min it the minimum key of items that can be added to yielded combinations.
--]]
local function unique_combinations (tbl, sub, min)
    sub = sub or {}
    min = min or 1
    return wrap (function ()
        if #sub > 0 then
            yield (sub) -- yield short combination.
        end
        if #sub < #tbl then
            for i = min, #tbl do    -- iterate over longer combinations.
                for combo in unique_combinations (tbl, append (sub, tbl [i]), i + 1) do
                    yield (combo)
                end
            end
        end
    end)
end
            
for combo in unique_combinations {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'} do
    print (table.concat (combo, ', '))
end
```

Comment: Damn, that's exactly what I needed, just much more well written than I could ever do. ;)

Answer (score 0):

For a tables with consecutive integer keys starting at 1 like yours you can simply use the length operator `#`. Your `tablelen` function is superfluous.

Using `table` as a local variable name shadows Lua's table library. I suggest you use `tbl` or some other name that does not prevent you from using `table`'s methods.

The issue with your code can be solved by printing some values for debugging:

```
local arr = {"a","b","c","d","e","f"}


function spellsub(tbl,start,offset)
  
local str = tbl[start]
print("first str:", str)
  print(string.format("loop from %d to %d", start+offset, #tbl+1-(start+offset)))
  for i = start+offset, (#tbl+1)-(start+offset) do
    print(string.format("tbl[%d]: %s", i+1, tbl[i+1]))
    str = str..","..tbl[i+1]
  end
  return str
end

print(spellsub(arr,1,2))    -- Outputs: "a,d,e" correctly
print(spellsub(arr,2,2))    -- Outputs: "b"     supposed to be "b,e,f"
```

prints:

```
first str:  a
loop from 3 to 4
tbl[4]: d
tbl[5]: e
a,d,e
first str:  b
loop from 4 to 3
b
```

As you see your second loop does not ran as the start value is already greater than the limit value. Hence you only print the first value `b`

I don't understand how your code is related to what you want to achieve so I'll leave it up to you to fix it.

Comment: Oh yeah, but what I need was more a function that would return element no. 2 with the remaining elements after an offset of 2. As per the example the correct output would have been "b,e,f" and not "b,d,f". But good reminder.